# RXJS side-effect execution order

Tags: angular, rxjs, side-effects

I have this huge object that I want to be able to set with a one simple function like below

```
  private setPerson = (partialPerson: Partial<Person>) => {
    this.person$.next({ ...this.person$.value, ...partialPerson });
  };
```

But when some of the properties changes I want to be able to run a side-effect like this

```
  personNameEffect$ = this.person$.pipe(
    map(({ name }) => name),
    distinct(),
    tap((name) => {
      // Do some complex calculation 
      this.person$.next({ ...this.person$.value, firstName: name });
    })
  );

  constructor() {
    this.personNameEffect$.subscribe()
  }
```

This works like I want it to, but the issue is the execution order of these steps, this is what I think is happening:

1. `setPerson` function is called with a partial object
2. The side-effect is ran and setting the values (Keeping old value from call before)
3. The next inside `setPerson` is ran and overwriting what the side-effect have changed

How can I fix this execution order? I want the next to set the values and then the side-effect to run.
Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-ndcjcp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link to a playground where this can be reproduced in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely related to the nested `next` calls and/or convoluted logic flow.  Furthermore getting the value out of a `BehaviorSubject` using `value` is generally frowned upon as its not reactive.

I have modelled your problem in a more reactive flow ie:

Use the `BehaviorSubject` only for pushing updates rather than a complete `Person`. Therefore no longer using it as a store, and avoiding having to update itself:

```
personUpdates$ = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<Person>>({});
```

`person$` stream accumulates these updates, and effectively stores the 'current' person:

```
person$ = this.personUpdates$.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {
      name: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    } as Person)
  );
```

Because of the change to the `BehaviorSubject`, the effect no longer needs to access it's `value`:

```
personNameEffect$ = this.person$.pipe(
    map(({name}) => name),
    distinct(),
    tap((name) => {
      console.log('Name changed detected');
      this.personUpdates$.next({ firstName: name });
    })
  );
```

Finally `setName` and `setLastName` are simplified, again due to the the `BehaviorSubject` only requiring a partial value.

```
  setName = (name: string) => {
    this.personUpdates$.next({ name });
  };
  setLastName = (lastName: string) => {
    this.personUpdates$.next({ lastName });
  };
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-kzexrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html